# How to secure access to build system credentials?

Tags: passwords, account-security

We have a build system, which fetches the sources and executes build commands. At present a dedicated person (build master) does the fetching with her personal account in the source control system.

We'd like to automate the build process. How can access to the source control system be secured?

I see an option to create a "shared account" (let's call it `buildmaster`) so that the user who is authorised to do the build would use a script with `buildmaster`'s credentials (in our case - username/password) to fetch the sources. How could then `buildmaster`'s password be made available to only those users who are authorised to run (production) builds?

Comment: Without knowing what the authenticating software is, we cannot answer this, but you've not told us anything about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your build is probably executed by a non-interactive program.  In Windows, for example, it would run as a service.

The service would be configured with a service account, which has its own user ID and password.  In your case the user ID would be "buildmaster."

If you have a need for a human being to trigger the build, there would need to be some means to tell your service to start a build, e.g. a UI.  You would not want to use the buildmaster account directly.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, just as I wrote in the question, a service account is needed. Then, how could the secret part of its credentials (password, or a private key) be protected?

Comment: Depends on your O/S.  See [this link](http://serverfault.com/questions/777233/where-and-how-is-the-password-stored-for-the-account-associated-with-a-windows-s) for Windows, and [this tech note](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn408190.aspx) on some options for managing the passwords.